# Finding matching strings in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I have `col D` (in *sheet1* called Students), `col A` (in *Sheet2* called Students too) and `col B` (in sheet2 called Age).  In `colD` there are a lot of similar Students names that are sorted from A to Z.

I have this code that finds matched students name and put his age in `col D` (*sheet1*):

```
Set rngSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
For Each rngSearch In Drng
    Set rngFound = Arng.Find(What:=rngSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
    'if studentname is found:
     If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
         rngSearch.Offset(0, 0) = rngFound.Offset(0, 1)
     Else
         rngSearch.Offset(0, 0) = "-"  
     End If
Next
```

I want to loop `col D` once and if exists a match students name in `colA` (*sheet2*), I want to copy in `colD` (*sheet1*) the B column (sheet2) that matches to `colA` (*sheet2*).

I sorted `colD` because I don't want to loop every similar students name.  I mean: if a student name (for example: Andrew) in colD matches to a student name ('Andrew') in `colA`, then copy `colB` (matches to col A- for example Andrew has 15 years old) in `colD` (*sheet1*).  And if the string 'Andrew' is repeated in `colD` (I found it in another cells), don't loop for it again `colB` (*sheet2*), but copy the value from the first string.

For example:

*(Sheet1)*

> ```
> colD: Students:    
> row1: Andrew         
> row2: Andrew         
> row3: Andrew         
> row4: Andrew         
> row5: Andrew         
> row6: Andrew         
> row7: Ben         
> row8: Ben         
> row9: Edoardo         
> row10: Helen         
> row11: Leonardo         
> row12: Leonardo         
> row13: Robert         
> rowN: ..
> ```

*(Sheet2)*

> ```
>       Students:  colB: Age:       
> row1: Michael          16         
> row2: Timoth           20         
> row3: Andrew           15         
> row4: Edoardo          19         
> row5: Ben              13         
> row6: Robert           24         
> row7: Helen            17
> ```

What I want:

*(Sheet1)*

> ```
> colD: Students:        
> row1: 15         
> row2: 15         
> row3: 15         
> row4: 15         
> row5: 15        
> row6: 15         
> row7: 13         
> row8: 13         
> row9: 19         
> row10: 17         
> row11: 0         
> row12: 0         
> row13: 24         
> rowN: ..
> ```

Can anyone help me to optimize this code, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As in a lot of cases, you don't need [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) to do what you're trying to accomplish. The best thing to do here is simply use one of the built in formulas. In this case, you want [VLOOKUP](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php). Using `VLOOKUP`, there's no need to sort the sheet.

```
VLOOKUP(sheet1!$A1,sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE)
```

But this is Code Review, so one is in order.

---

I'm assuming this is a typo.

```
Set rngSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
For Each rngSearch In Drng
```

And what you really mean is:

```
Drng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
For each rngSearch In Drng
```

Which makes me want to mention that I *really* hate Hungarian notation. I like this mixed and reversed notation even less. The IDE will tell you that it's a `Range`, but if you really just need your code to spell it out, just spell it out. At least be consistent.

> rngSearch >> searchRange
>
> Drng >> rngD >> columnD

---

If your subroutine needs the sheet to be sorted, then your subroutine should sort sort it itself, but I recommend against sorting the sheet at all unless your user expects the sheet to be sorted a certain way. Messing with the sort order unexpectly makes for a poor user experience. Albeit not as poor of an experience as your code producing unexpected results.

---

This line scrolls off the screen. You should try to keep everything on the screen if possible.

```
Set rngFound = Arng.Find(What:=rngSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole,   SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
```

You've got two options to help solve this. You can either skip the verbose method of using argument identifiers and simply not pass the missing argument into Find,

```
Set rngFound = Arng.Find(rngSearch, , xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, xlNext, False, False)
```

Or use line continuations.

```
Set rngFound = Arng.Find(What:=rngSearch, _
                         LookIn:=xlValues, _
                         LookAt:=xlWhole, _  
                         SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                         SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                         MatchCase:=False, _
                         SearchFormat:=False)
```

---

There's a small optimization to be had by only searching column D until there are no more values. Find the last used cell in the sheet and only search until you reach that cell. As it is, I think your code does many more iterations than it has to.

Comment: You're right, but I solved my problem yet. However, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: You're welcome. Welcome to Code Review by the way.

Comment: Also, if you solved your issue, consider posting an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you. I really appreciate the site! I post the code below.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem. Here is the code:

```
Set rngSearch = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D:D")
For Each rngSearch In Drng
    'all activities are searched in Arng:
    Set rFnd = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D2:D" & lastRowD).Find(What:=sText, LookAt:=xlPart)
    Set rngFound = Arng.Find(What:=rngSearch, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If Not rFnd Is Nothing Then
        rngSearch.Offset(0, 0) = rngSearch.Offset(-1, 0) 'if found multiple strings, don't loop column A but copy the row above
    Else
        'if activity is found:
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            rngSearch.Offset(0, 0) = rngFound.Offset(0, 1)
        Else
            rngSearch.Offset(0, 0) = "0"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Presented Solutions are good, but CR answers should be about explaining **how** and **why** your code is better, not just a code dump.